# Visual Studio 2022 Keeps Deleting Page.aspx Code Behind

Tags: visual-studio

Every time I add a label, spaces, buttons, or make any edits to the page via Design mode, it deletes almost all of my code behind.  Visual Studio just started doing this recently.  I haven't changed any settings, updated the application, or made any changes that would cause this.  It seems like a bug.  Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its very aggravating. In mine its deleting code in the page and also adding random letters.

Seemed to start doing this with the last update. Today is 4/16/2020 so the most current version at this point in time.

Best is to use an older version until this is fixed.